# Namerror being thrown

Tags: python, cython

I'm new to Cython so please bear with me.
On compiling the python code to Cython on windows, EPC_test.pyd is generated fine.
But on importing the EPC_test, I'm getting a NameError.

EPC_test.pyx (code snippet)

```
persps = ['GU','GR','RL']
for persp in persps:

#filter list by perspective
arr_persp = rows[rows[:,1]==persp]
..

>>> import EPC_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "EPC_test.pyx", line 1191, in init EPC_test (EPC_test.c:23097)
for persp in persps:
NameError: name 'persps' is not defined
```

Do I need to cdef `persps` somewhere? As far as my understanding goes, all python code needn't have any C definitions and should be directly compiled. Please advise